# How to delete selected area?

Tags: fabricjs

I'm working with fabricjs and am trying to create something like Paint, so I can open an image and edit it.

I would like to be able to select an area on this img, and delete it (-> fill it with white color), how can I have a visible selected area, get its coordinates, and fill it with white?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311038/fabric-js-eraser-issue-canvas.  You could approximate by creating a rect with the same color as the background over the area you want to hide.

Comment: Yes thx i think i'll do that =)